# aspnet - Failure when adding migration: Value cannot be null, parameter name: property

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

i already looking in the web for this error and i cant find any usefull. i tried to create database with entity framework in dotnet but i got this error. any suggestion what i am doing wrong? i would like to provide code but i dont know which one. i'll update it later if its necessary. now i just attach the error.

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: property
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMapper.FindMapping(IProperty property)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MySqlMigrationsSqlGenerationHelper.ColumnDefinition(String schema, Strin
>   g table, String name, Type clrType, String type, Nullable`1 unicode, Nullable`1 maxLength, Boolean rowVersion, Boolean
>   nullable, Object defaultValue, String defaultValueSql, String computedColumnSql, IAnnotatable annotatable, IModel model
>   , MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.ColumnDefinition(AddColumnOperation operation, IM
>   odel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(CreateTableOperation operation, IModel m
>   odel, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder, Boolean terminate)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(CreateTableOperation operation, IModel m
>   odel, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(MigrationOperation operation, IModel mod
>   el, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(IReadOnlyList`1 operations, IModel model
>   )
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.GenerateUpSql(Migration migration)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String
>   contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
>   Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: property
>   reformat stacktrace

any response would be great. thank you very much.

Comment: as nice as the exception info is, we need code to tell you where the error is.

Comment: @Hack yeah which part of the code ? i am affraid i takes to long if i put it all in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys for helping me. i now know the problem. it just typo in the table name.

```
public DbSet<Account> tblAccount {get;set;}
```

then i write this in the migration code

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "tblAccounts ",
            columns: table => new ....
```

i am sorry i didn't realize it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send null value for a parameter/column which is of type not null.

Comment: i dont even know that i am sending null value. could you give me a clue where i could start search it in the code?

Comment: I cannot hint you without the code. But you can verify the value for each properties if the list is not huge.

Comment: Thank you @Rex for the help. i can now resolve the problem.